# AirPort Extreme: slow upload via ethernet, but fast via wireless

Tags: network, airport

I have a new dual-band AirPort Extreme base station (v7.6.1). I've used it to create a wireless network, and I also connect my Mac Pro (Early 2009, running 10.8.2) via ethernet. When I run a speed test on my iPhone (to test the wireless speed), I get an upload speed of 1.45 Mbps (not super fast, but I only pay for 1 Mbps so I'll take it). When I run the same test on the Mac Pro (to test the wired speed) I get only 0.13 Mbps. The AirPort Utility (v6.1) doesn't provide a lot of options, so I've been unable to resolve this. How can I fix my ethernet upload speeds?

In summary:

AirPort Extreme

Wireless Upload: 1.45 Mbps

Wired Upload: 0.13 Mbps

Comment: I had a somewhat similar problem last year, though the details differ a great deal. After many attempts at diagnosing the problem and much head scratching, I reset my AirPort Extreme to the factory condition and set it up from scratch. That solved my problem. I suggest you try it too, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by playing around with my network settings. In System Preferences > Network > Ethernet 1 > Advanced > Hardware I manually set the Speed to "100baseTX" and Duplex to "full-duplex" and my upload speeds have returned to normal.

Comment: "Auto" should have worked out of the box. Check/replace your ethernet cables, there might be something wrong with them physically, or it you have other router/switches/hubs connected, they might be the culprit.